# How can I tell companion influence level in KotOR 2?

Tags: star-wars-kotor-2

How can I tell how much influence I've got with my NPC companions in Knights of the Old Republic 2: The Sith Lords?

The game tells you when you gain dark side or light side, and also tells you when you gain or lose influence with your companions, but whilst it gives you a nice graph of your overall light/dark allegiance, there doesn't seem to be any way to tell your total current influence level with your various NPC companions?

Comment: I think it would be worth putting the full name of the game in the title in this case. No everyone will know the accepted shortening of all games.

Comment: @Chris I think in this case (as it's a very long name) it should be ok... furthermore, a quick Google search will tell you what it stands for IMHO

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no way in game but [there is a mod that does this.](http://knightsoftheoldrepublic.filefront.com/file/Remote_Tells_Influence;87769) I have not tried it but it's probably worth a shot.

Comment: Ahh that looks promising, thanks. Disappointing that there's no inbuilt way to do this, but glad that the community have stepped up. Will try it out later.

Answer (score 3):

While there is no clear, direct, 'Influence Meter', or anything so crude in the game, there is *one* reasonably reliable metric for measuring influence - Alignment.

Companions with whom you have high influence will tend to mirror the alignment of the Exile - this is particularly easy to see with a dark side Exile; as your influence rises, the backdrop of the portraits of your various companions on their character sheets will get darker and redder, reflecting their fall to the dark side with you.

(N.B., some companions, such as Kreia, will never shift alignment, and since most companions start out at least somewhat on the light side of the spectrum, it's a bit tougher for a light side Exile to notice the shift.)

Also, with negative influence the Exile's companions will align with the opposite polarity. Meaning, if you lose influence with anyone as a dark side character they will align with the light side to oppose you. Gaining negative influence also unlocks conversations and the ability to create jedi like positive influence does.